# Manipulate Command and Plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

```
xstep = (xhi - xlo)/100
x = Table [xlo + (i - 1)*xstep, {i, 1, 101}];
a0 = 9
a1 = 4
a2 = 1
a3 = 0
Ca0 = Table[5 + (i - 1), {i, 1, 101}];
Da1 = Table[a1*x];
Ea2 = Table[a2*(x^2)];
y = Da1 + Ea2 + a0;
data = Transpose@{x, y};
ListPlot[{data}]
```

I have the following code and wants to combine this with Manipulate command so that when I change the a0, a1, a2,a3, the output of graph changes. like in the following command

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a* x^2 + b *x + c, {x, -100, 100}], {a, -1, 1, 0.2}, {b, -10, 
  10, 1}, {c, -50, +50, 5}]
```

Comment: You have defined `Da1` and `Ea2` erroneously, what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Creating a series, first one equal to a1*x and Second one (a2*x^2). after that, I have to create a series y, which is equal to y = Da1 + Ea2 + a0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised and only relies on basic Mathematica programming skills, and is therefore unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function `data` with arguments `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, `xhi`, and `xlo`.

```
xstep = (xhi - xlo)/100;
x = Table[xlo + (i - 1)*xstep, {i, 1, 101}];
Ca0 = Table[5 + (i - 1), {i, 1, 101}];
Da1 = a1*x;
Ea2 = a2*(x^2);
y = Da1 + Ea2 + a0;
data[a0_, a1_, a2_, xhi_, xlo_] = Transpose@{x, y};
```

Then, use `Manipulate`,

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data[a0, a1, a2, xhi, xlo], Frame -> True], {{xhi, 9}, 1, 9,
   1}, {{xlo, 2}, 1, 5, 1}, {{a0, 9}, 1, 10, 1}, {{a1, 4}, 1, 10, 
  1}, {{a2, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, ControlType -> LabeledSlider]
```

[image]

Comment: why the graph output is not changing, when I am changing parameters value

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan Try restarting your kernel.

Comment: how i can do that please

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan Run `Quit[]`.

Comment: @ Anjan Kumar last thing how i can change my x-axis range let say from -500 to 500

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> {{-500, 500}, Full}` to change only x-axis range.

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan I think you have not copied it correctly because there should be no `Frame` in `PlotRange` attribute